# Django REST framework:Use OneToOneField can't GET

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

when i use Django REST framework ,and use Use OneToOneField and RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView can't GET by pk;
my code are as follows:

models.py

```
class UserAccount(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=45) 
    password = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=16) 

class UserContactInfo(models.Model):
    userAccount = models.OneToOneField(UserAccount, primary_key=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=45)
```

serializers.py

```
class UserAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAccount
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password')


class UserContactInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserContactInfo
        fields = ('userAccount', 'phone_number', 'email')
```

views.py

```
class UserContactInfoDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = UserAccount.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserContactInfoSerializer
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^ContactInfo/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',    views.UserContactInfoDetail.as_view()),
    ]
```

Ok , when i try to GET UserContactInfo data:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/ContactInfo/1/
```

and go wrong:

```
AttributeError at /ContactInfo/1/
'UserAccount' object has no attribute 'userAccount_id'

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ContactInfo/1/
.....
```

Who can help me to fix it . Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have typo in a view, in a queryset:
`queryset = UserAccount.objects.all()` instead of `UserContactInfo.objects.all()`

Comment: Thank You!! It's is my careless mistake!